# How can I multiply and divide by odd constants in arm Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I don’t know how to multiply or divide by an odd constant. In the image ([Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9rl3.jpg) ), I know how to solve the first two problem (with the left and the right shift) but not the last two.

How can I do the exercise number 3 and number 4?
I resolved the first like this:

```
ADD r1, r2, lsl #3
```

So I’d Like something like that for the last two.

Comment: You know that `x*5=x*4+x` right? Also `(3/4)*x=(3*x)/4=(2*x+x)/4`. Any problems doing these? PS: these will take more than a single instruction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please be aware that this isn't a homework service - asking a good SO question is about documenting your attempts to solve a problem and then asking for help with something specific that you don't understand, rather than asking for someone to write code for you.

Comment: You're only dividing by even constants, powers of 2 in fact, so it's just shifts.  Is `(3/4) * x` really supposed to be evaluated with integer math?  If so, the answer is zero because `(3/4)` truncates to 0.  Otherwise, are you supposed to be keeping some fraction bits in the other cases where you divide by `4`?

Comment: I don’t know I only have to put the value from 3/4 * r2 in r1

Comment: Did U figure this out? I too want to know how to multiply w/ a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) MUL r1, r2, lsl #2 → ADD r1, r1, r2
2) MUL r1, r2, lsl #1 → ADD r1, r1, r2 →  MUL r1, r1, lsr #2